Cannot reproduce Continuous Ranked Probability Score (CRPS) from Python package
The Continuous Ranked Probability Score (CRPS) is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{CRPS}(F, x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy
\end{equation}
I am trying to intuitively understand, in steps, how a CRPS of 0.625 is obtained by the properscoring Python library using ensemble values of [1, 2, 3, 4] and an observed value of 3.5. Another python package (CRPS) also gives 0.625, so I am confident that 0.625 is the result I want.
Python code that gives 0.625
import numpy as np
import properscoring as ps

ensemble_values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
observed_value = 3.5

ps_result = ps.crps_ensemble(observed_value, ensemble_values)
print(ps_result)  # 0.625

Step by step calculation that gives 0.875
The CDF of the ensemble is: 
F(1) = 0.25, F(2) = 0.5, F(3) = 0.75, F(4) = 1.0
The observed value is 3.5, so the CDF of the observed value H(x) is a step function that is 0 for all values less than 3.5 and 1 for all values greater than or equal to 3.5.
Therefore:
H(1) = H(2) = H(3) = 0 and H(4) = 1
We sum the squared difference at each ensemble point:
For x1: (0.25 - 0)**2 = 0.0625
For x2: (0.5 - 0)**2 = 0.25
For x3: (0.75 - 0)**2 = 0.5625
For x4: (1.0 - 1)**2 = 0

CRPS = 0.0625 + 0.25 + 0.5625 + 0 = 0.875

Any idea what the missing piece of the puzzle is?

this SE answer may help provide some understanding around CRPS: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64320/54731

You need to evaluate the integral a little more carefully. Specifically, the integrand changes midway through the interval $[3,4]$, at your observation $3.5$:
$$ \begin{align*}
\mathrm{CRPS}(F, x) =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy \\
=&\int_1^4 \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy \\
=&\int_1^2 \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy
+\int_2^3 \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy \\
& \quad +\int_3^{3.5} \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy
+\int_{3.5}^4 \left( F(y) - \mathbb{1}(y - x) \right)^2 \, dy \\
=&\int_1^2 \left( 0.25-0 \right)^2 \, dy
+\int_2^3 \left( 0.5-0 \right)^2 \, dy \\
& \quad 
+\int_3^{3.5} \left( 0.75-0 \right)^2 \, dy
+\int_{3.5}^4 \left( 0.75-1 \right)^2 \, dy \\
=& 0.25^2+0.5^2+\frac{1}{2}0.75^2+\frac{1}{2}0.25^2 \\
=& 0.625
\end{align*}$$
